In multiple regressions, why would adding interaction terms of one variable increase the beta score and significance of that variable?
I have a revise and resubmission manuscript - the reviewer is asking us to add additional interaction terms for one of the variables, let's say, variable A (dummy coded). I added interaction terms of this variable: AxB, AxC, AxD, etc. (some dummy coded, some continuous) into the new regression model in a new block. While not many of the interaction terms were significant on the outcome variables (continuous), this made variable A extremely significant and with a high standardized beta score in the new models (but in the original regression models without the interaction terms, variable A was very weakly related with the dependent variables, and in some instances not significant)
Why would this happen and this is an issue?

When there is an interaction in a model, the main effect in the output (i.e., the line in the table that explicitly says "$A$") does not mean the same thing as it does when there is not an interaction in the model.  For a model with a binary, categorical variable, $A$, that is not included in any interactions, the estimated coefficient for $A$ is the change in the predicted mean value for $Y$ associated with moving from the reference level of $A$ (e.g., placebo) to the indicated level of $A$ (e.g., active treatment).  On the other hand, if there is an interaction $A\times B$ included in the model, then what is listed as "$A$" only refers to the change in $Y$ associated with a change in $A$ when $B=0$, either because the value of $B$ is exactly $0$ (heart rate is $0$ beats per minute—dead, even though there are no dead patients in the dataset), or because $B$ is at its reference level (e.g., no family history of disease).
